# How do I get this automated java login to work using JSoup?

Tags: java

I managed to source this code from another thread, but I cant seem to get it to work, with lots of red lines! What do i need to change in order to make it work for my webpage that needs a login?

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://login.to/")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .timeout(12000)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

Connection.Response loginFormFilled = Jsoup.connect("https://login.to/")
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
        .followRedirects(true)
        .referrer("https://login.to/")
        .data("LOGON", "user")//check the form to find field name for user name
        .data("PASSWORDS", "pass")//check the form to find field name for user password
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();
        int statusCode = loginFormFilled.statusCode();
        Map<String, String> cookies = loginFormFilled.cookies();
```

EDIT: NEW CODE

```
 try{
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php")
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
        .timeout(12000)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

Connection.Response loginFormFilled = Jsoup.connect("https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php")
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
    .followRedirects(true)
    .referrer("https://login.to/")
    .data("team-name", "stockblockers 99")//check the form to find field name for user name
    .data("team-password", "monkey1")//check the form to find field name for user password
    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();
    int statusCode = loginFormFilled.statusCode();
    Map<String, String> cookies = loginFormFilled.cookies();
    System.out.println(statusCode);
 }catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();}
 }
}
```

EDIT 2: COOKIES NOT WORKING!
So I have an automated java login written. Once the program executes that method, and the 200 status code  is returned to show it is successful, it means I have logged in (right?). However, when the program tries to download the HTML of the webpage and output it on the screen, the HTML outputted is the login screen, not the HTML of the webpage once you have logged in.

I'm guessing this has something to do with cookies, as there is a yellow line under 'cookies' below

```
    Map<String, String> cookies = loginFormFilled.cookies();
```

Comment: Red  lines under 'Connection' 'loginForm', 'loginFormFilled' and 'Map'

Comment: Don't add different questions to the same post. Create a new post including all relevant code & any errors produced

Comment: 90 minute rule on stackoverflow prevents me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`execute`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#execute()) throws an `IOException` which is a checked exception. Either surround the code in a `try/catch` clause or declare the method as throwing the exception

Comment: What do I put in the catch clause bit?

Comment: catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();) now put in, but 'connection', and 'Map' still in red?

Comment: Map fixed by adding java.util.Map, still red under connection

Comment: Post your complete code and those errors too in the question

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it by adding another import for Connection. Cheers for the help, appreciated.

Comment: Here's a useful link on how to post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the meantime consider accepting this answer - click the 'tick'

Comment: Can you please advise me on my latest problem, as shown in Edit 2